# Cocos2d-js game hangs on loding screen with warning about Synchronous XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, webkit, cocos2d-js

in my Cocos2d-JS game I have a problem, that the browser hangs on the loading screen in Chrome and Firefox ( also on Safari, but more inconsistently ) 
It is really hard to find out where the problem lies.
However, one warning I am getting is:

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/

problem occurs with cocos2d-js-v3.6.js - cocos2d-js-v3.9.js
( didnt try any others )

Any Ideas what I could do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your applications URL scheme. it should be https://aplicationurl.